# how to compile ns3-lbt, while I am trying to compile it shows error

Tags: ubuntu, ns-3

**I am trying to compiling ns3-lbt, while building waf it shows error. I am using ns3.32 on ubuntu 20.04.**

```
  In function 'char* strncpy(char*, const char*, size_t)',
    inlined from 'omr_error_t expandString(char*, const char*, BOOLEAN)' at omrtracemisc.cpp:137:12:
/.../fedora_riscv_mnt/usr/include/bits/string_fortified.h:106:34: 
error: 'char* __builtin_strncpy(char*, const char*, long unsigned int)' output truncated 
before terminating nul copying 6 bytes from a string of the same length [-Werror=stringop-truncation]
  106 |   return __builtin___strncpy_chk (__dest, __src, __len, __bos (__dest));
      |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```